# What does "docker start" "-d" option mean?

Tags: docker

I know what "docker start" is and it is required to start docker for some image. But what "-d" option mean? Should I use it when I start docker image second, third etc. times? I am using it and the output is "creating..." ("docker down" writes "stopping" and it is fine, but it also writes "removing" and it is distburbing). I would like to just restart my image and not re-create it. Does "-d" controls it? Or should I use "docker restart" for that?

I know that Docker has docs https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/start/ but everyone can see the rating of them (I contributed as well in this rating).

Comment: You linked to `docker-compose` docs, and there is no `docker-compose start -d`. There is a [`docker-compose up -d`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/). There's also no `docker start -d`. There is a [`docker run -d`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-d` is short for "detached mode", which means the container is running in the background. You can read more about [the difference between detached and foreground running here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached-vs-foreground). This will help answer your question about whether you should use it or not.

Hope this answers your question